# Conditional Con tool setting rgb value for true statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have a raster with some NoData values. I am trying to set these values to black. I have looked at the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm).

This is what I have so far

`Con(IsNull('MyImage'),0,'MyImage')`

This produces a grey scale image. I want to maintain the color in the image and just set the NoData values to black.

I am using ArcMap 10.3

Comment: It sounds like this a multiband raster. I think you will have to change the null value in all of the bands separately and then make a composite of the results.

Comment: Okay so I should create a layer for each band then run the Con tool on each of those. Then use the Composite Bands tool the bring them back together. Thanks!